# Use SQL formula from different table

Tags: sql

I have a formula:

```
COUNT(T1.ID)/COUNT(T2.ID) * 100
```

I need to get the answer:

```
select count(t1.id)/count(t2.id)*100 FROM T1
  inner join T2  on T1.id=T1.id 
WHERE T1.Status=0
```

I need to divide the count of `T1` where `T1.Status = 0` with the count
of all the records in `T2` and multiply it by `100`.

I tried this but the answer is wrong.  What is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to divide the count of the records from T1 where T1.Status = 0 with the count of all the records in T2, and multiply it by 100.

```
SELECT 100 * COUNT(t1.id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM T2) AS percent
  FROM T1
 WHERE T1.Status = 0;
```

Comment: You might need to coerce one of the values in the select-list expression into a floating point type so that the division is not an integer division.  It might be sufficient to multiply by 100.0 and parenthesize.

Answer (score 0):

Your join appears to be incorrect. Should it be:

```
select count(t1.id)/count(t2.id)*100 FROM T1 
  inner join T2  on T1.id=**T2**.id  
WHERE T1.Status=0
```

Comment: The join condition is incorrect, but that is only a small part of the problem.

Comment: I agree. If the id fields are integers they will need to be converted to decimals prior to the division as it may loose floating point.

Answer (score 0):

Your INNER JOIN was slightly wrong (you were using `T1.ID = T1.ID`, which is always true except when T1.ID is null). Fixing that should work.

```
select count(t1.id)/count(t2.id)*100 FROM T1
   inner join T2  
       on T1.id = T2.id 
WHERE t1.Status = 0
```

You should also note that the result for this should always be `100`, except when there is no items in `T1` with a `Status = 0` (in this case you will get a divide by zero error). This is because you are performing an `INNER JOIN`, so the number of rows from each table will always be the same as each other, the division will always equal 1.